# I want to drag a word or sentence from a pdf file in iOS. Is it possible or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pdf

I want to drag a word or sentence from a pdf file in iOS.

Is it possible or not?

Comment: Do you want to copy a text?

Comment: User should be able to select a word or sentence and then drag to some place where he/she can save that word for his/her reference.

Comment: @androidSingh You need to copy the text and create a cloned label with the text at the exact location where you selected and make the cloned label drag, so basically you need to find how to select a word, and copy from PDF.

Comment: @iphonic Yes, But how to select any word in a pdf file...???

Comment: @androidSingh [PoDoFo](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/) is a very good library to do PDF operations, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you hold your finger down on a pdf document, a magnifier will show up, allowing you to select a word. Once you have selected the word, you can use the pop-up menu to copy the word to the pasteboard. It can then be pasted somewhere else.

There is no way to drag the selected word.